# attach boxed title: blank title to hand write

Tags: tcolorbox

Latex friends,

I use tcolorbox and need "Blank field" in title and i will hand writing into this Field.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tikzset{fancytitle/.style ={fill=red, text=white}}
\newtcolorbox
{mybox}[1]{tikznode boxed title,enhanced,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},boxed title style={size=small,colback=red},title={#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Name} 1/ This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{mybox}\

\begin{mybox}{} 2/ Need display field "Title box" to write
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{\tiny .....} 3/ tiny point...\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

How can display "Titel box" in 2. mybox and if any can create "big box" that easy to write.

I will use different beautiful box for fillable form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly.

Is that what you want?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%\tikzset{fancytitle/.style ={fill=red, text=white}}

\tcbset{whitetitle/.style={boxed title style={size=small,colback=white}}}

\tcbset{redtitle/.style={boxed title style={size=small,colback=red}}}

\newtcolorbox
{mybox}[2][]{%tikznode boxed title,
#1,enhanced,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},title={#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[redtitle]{Name} 1/ This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{mybox}\

\begin{mybox}[whitetitle]{\phantom{Title box}} 2/ Need display field "Title box" to write
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[redtitle]{\tiny .....} 3/ tiny point...\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that is right what i want.